# Check if a entry start with http

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a python code and using tkinter but i know how to check if a entry is empty before click the button, now i want to know how to check if the entry start with http after click the button and before running the program.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) should help.

Answer (score 1):

As @Olvin Roght said in the comments, this should work:

```py
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
def get():
    string2 = e.get()
    if string2.startswith("http"):
       #what ever you need
```

Also, you can't check the entry before running the program. Please edit your question to include more detail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: perfect, tahnks you very much :)

Comment: As written this example doesn't work, since you call `e.get()` before the user has a chance to enter anything.

Comment: ```string.startswith() == "http"``` doesn't work in Python, where it would rather be ```string.startswith("http")```.

Comment: Better not to use `string` as variable name as it is the name of built-in module.

Comment: Ok @acw1668 I will change it